# Windows XP embedded lost forever if HDD formatted?

Tags: windows

Some time ago, my company bought a second-hand LaCie Ethernet disk from another company that was going into liquidation. I've been asked to look into it, and I've found that machine has been formatted. After some preliminary reading, I was expecting Windows XP to be embedded in the disk.

If the machine was indeed formatted before sale (as opposed to just being faulty), did that completely remove the embedded Windows from it also? Is it possible to recover or reinstall Windows on this machine?

Answer (score 1):

Formatting the drives would remove the OS as well. You can reinstall the system using a [Restore CD image](http://www.lacie.com/support/drivers/driver.htm?id=10111) appropriate for the version of the board in your unit.

Answer (score 0):

You can always reinstall any windows on the machine. AS for if you can find the embedded Windows on the disk, it all depends if the partitions were formatted or the whole disk. If the disk has been formatted there is nothing left on that disk. If they only formatted the Windows partition you may still have the windows recovery partition on the disk. Run a Windows installation disk and look for yourself if the disk is still partitioned.